# how to fadeIn when appending and fadeOut when removing

Tags: jquery

I wanted to give fadeIn effect while append some element and fadeOut effect when removing the element.

So, I tried this

```
$(selector).closest('div').append(<p class="vali">hi this is test</p>).fadeIn();
$('.vali').fadeOut(); //this works because it is appended that is there is element
```

But when there is no element and when appended can I give fadeIn effect directly **without setting it first `display: none;` and giving fadeIn effect**

Answer (score 1):

You could create a CSS rule (*if the problem is that you are setting it with jquery*) that makes the `.vali` elements be `display:none`.

```
.vali{
    display:none;
}
```

This way, when you append elements in the DOM they will initially be hidden, and appear due to the `.fadeIn()`

---

Also your html code should be in quotes, otherwise you will get a syntax error.

```
.append('<p class="vali">hi this is test</p>')
```

Answer (score 1):

I've made it work something like this

```
$(selector).closest('div').append(<p class="vali">hi this is test</p>).hide().fadeIn();
```